# How to save multiple records from Json structure in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, sql-insert

I have this situation. I got this Json that I get from a POST call, I need to insert into my database the same record (for example Id: I have to insert it twice) every time this one gets repeated.

```
{
    Information [{
         "Id": "126565",
         "Name": "Martin",
         "Country": "USA",
         "City": "California",
         "Job": "Doctor"
    },
    {
        "Id":"235269",
        "Name": "Emma",
        "Country": "USA",
        "City": "New York",
        "Job": "Nurse"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried `foreach` but it saves always the first record only.

```
foreach (Operators op in response.operator)
{
    var operator_response = (HttpWebResponse)operator_request.GetResponse();
    operator_responseString = new StreamReader(operator_response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    operator_Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OPERATORS_Response>(operator_responseString);
    string operator_ID = OPERATORS_Response.operators.First();

    // to insert in the database 
    cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into Operator_table (id_operator) values (?)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_operator", operator_ID.Id);
}
```

Comment: In your foreach, use the iterator variable `op` instead of `OPERATORS_Response.operators.First()`...

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM?  That way you could just insert the deserialized object directly into the database?  That would be a lot easier than parameterized SQL.  

As for your specific question, is response.operator equivalent to the information array in your JSON?  Assuming it is, your primary problem is that when you create the foreach statement and the op iterator variable (foreach(Operators op....), you aren't actually using op.  You're still using the whole list inside the loop, then just getting the first one.  Either use the op variable, or deserialize it to an array first.

Comment: @DanCsharpster, thank you for the advice, I will implement it so it's easier for future developments

Answer (score 1):

`First()` will return you top 1 record. You need `foreach` to iterate the operators, something like below -

```
foreach (Operators op in response.operator)
{
 var operator_response = (HttpWebResponse)operator_request.GetResponse();
 operator_responseString = new StreamReader(operator_response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
 operator_Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OPERATORS_Response>(operator_responseString);

 //remove First()
 var operators = OPERATORS_Response.operators;

 //iterate each operator
 foreach(var operator in operators)
 {
     // to insert in the database 
     cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into Operator_table (id_operator) values (?)", conn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_operator", operator.Id);
 }   
}
```